# Slightly spammy behavior

Tags: discussion, etiquette, specific-user

I don't know if it's too early to call this a problem, but two usernames with seemingly identical style, notation and subject matter have spammed a total of 10 questions today. (Not that asking a lot of questions is wrong, it's just that they all show no effort, and the user seems unresponsive and bot-like.)

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/62889/mathproof-p

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/63013/edwardjones-jones

They seem to be rapid fire, and being posted without any effort to determine if there is a duplicate. I haven't fully absorbed from the meta posts when exactly this qualifies as a problem. At worst, it is a person posting an entire homework assignment, but of course we have little ability to prove that.

When should a concerned forum user do something, and what should they do?

Comment: Spammy behavior need not be spam. I think that the [spam] tag should be reserved for actual spam related topics. This is just a user (or two) which behaves very inappropriately.

Comment: Also, sock puppets in order to side step the six questions limitation is a reasonable cause for suspension, I believe.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ahh, these are much better tags... thank you.